# how to connect sound to samsung 49" monitor using Thunderbolt 2012 macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, sound-volume

Hello I have an upgraded 2012 macbook pro and I recently purchased a 49" Samsung Ultrawide monitor :). I connected the monitor using the thunderbolt. I know the sound will most likely work with hdmi but I'm trying to avoid using the converter.

So how can I get sound to come the Samsung monitor? I check the sound output settings and its not even option on here. If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Did you try just selecting C49HG9x… as that would appear to be the model number of a Samsung 49" monitor.

Comment: Yes I selected it and everything goes mute.